# Sending Objects to Players with game requests when custom open graph stories are deprecated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It says in the docs you cannot use instances of the standard Open Graph types and must use your own custom Open Graph type. However in version 2.8 of the Graph api, custom objects are deprecated. There is no mention of this on the game request doc page so I'm not sure if game request objects are now deprecated as well or if you can now send standard objects.

Comment: Hi did you make it work already? if so how did you do it?